# Raw block / other messages

Tags: client, blockchain, development, protocol, raw-data

Where can I find a raw version of the Bitcoin blocks and other messages that are sent between the Bitcoin clients?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wiki describes this:
 - https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#Common_structures

BlockExplorer will show the raw data.  For example:
 - http://blockexplorer.com/rawblock/00000000000008d11f13eed2e13f2765eceaf00de36e0ec040a10cc3738bdc74

Comment: The BlockExplorer shows data in human readable json format. The Protocol Specification page shows raw bytes of data, but to be used it would require cleaning up, and it's only one example per each case. To test developing applications one usually should have more test cases.

Comment: There are at least three open source projects that read from the wire which might give you guidance:


the Bitcoin client, libbitcoin: https://bitcoinconsultancy.com/wiki/index.php/Libbitcoin

and BitcoinJ